# Supose $N$ is a normal subgroup of order $p^n$. Then show that $\sigma (N)=N$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, automorphism-group

Let $G$  be a group of order $p^nm, \ p \nmid m$. Supose $N$ is a normal subgroup of order $p^n$. Then show that $\sigma (N)=N$ for **any**  automorphism $\sigma \in \text{Aut}(G)$.

I have tried in the way-

Suppose $H$ be the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing both $\sigma(N)$ and $N$.

My target is to show $|H|=p^n$.

One way to show this, we need to show $H\subset N$.

Suppose $H \nsubseteq N$, then  there exists at least an element, say, $g \in G \setminus \{H\}$  such that order of $g$  doesn't divide $p^n$.

How to show contradiction here ?

**Edit:**

I got the following answers but if we can prove the question in my direction of approach.

Comment: Do you know the Sylow theorems?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk, yes,but how does it ?

Comment: Note that $N$ is a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup. How many Sylow $p$-subgroups does $G$ have in total?

Comment: Here's a proof using the Sylow theorems (I'm doing this in a comment since it address the problem in a completely different way than you've approached it). $N$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup, and since it is normal it is the only $p$-Sylow subgroup (this is a consequence of the 2nd Sylow theorem, which says that $G$ acts by conjugation transitively on the $p$-Sylow subgroups). Since an automorphism will take $N$ to another subgroup of order $p^n$, it must take it to $N$ itself by uniqueness.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk, only one Sylow $p$-subgroup

Comment: Right, and as @NathanLowry noted, $\sigma(N)$ is also a Sylow $p$-subgroup! (make sure you understand why)

Comment: @diracdeltafunk, But I want to prove in the above direction. Can you help me there ?

Comment: You mean you don't want to use the Sylow theorems to solve this problem?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk,yes

Comment: I don't understand why, and also I can't think of any easy proofs which don't use the Sylow theorems. If you want, you could replicate the proof of Sylow II to solve this problem, but at that point why not just use the theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is a proof/hint which avoids using the Sylow theorems (again, not sure why this is desirable). We have that $$\lvert \sigma(N) N \rvert = \frac{\lvert \sigma(N) \rvert \lvert N \rvert}{\lvert \sigma(N) \cap N \rvert} = \frac{p^{2n}}{\lvert \sigma(N) \cap N \rvert}.$$

Since $N$ is normal, $\sigma(N)N$ is a subgroup of $G$, so its order divides $p^n m$. What does this tell you about the order of $\sigma(N) \cap N$?

Comment: it is looking to be order $p^n$

Comment: Yes, and this should let you finish the proof :)

Comment: Thanks for nice answer. However I am keeping open the answer intake if there is a proof in my direction of approach.

Comment: No worries at all. But I should say, this proof can be rewritten in the direction you were going! Note that $\sigma(N) N$ *is* the smallest subgroup containing both $N$ and $\sigma(N)$.

Comment: Yes, exactly, this answer serves my purpose with $H=\sigma(N) N$.